# Angular v4 typescript rest api

Tags: rest, angular, typescript

I'm new in angular v4 and I have problems with parse nested object from de rest api,Its a very simple case  I'll let the code speak for me, its a really basic code but I dont find the error.

The error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CarDetailComponent.html:7)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:12679)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12058)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12367)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12313)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12059)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12367)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12313)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12059)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13041)

Classes

```
import { JsonObject, JsonProperty } from "json2typescript";

@JsonObject
export class User {
  @JsonProperty("id", Number)
  public id: number = undefined;
  @JsonProperty("email", String)
  public email: string = undefined;
  constructor(
  ) { }
}

@JsonObject
export class Car {
  @JsonProperty("id", Number)
  public id: number = undefined;
  @JsonProperty("brand", String)
  public brand: string = undefined;
  @JsonProperty("createdby", User)
  public createdBy: User = undefined

  constructor(
  ) { }
}
```

(Service: car.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from "app/car/car";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  private baseHost: string = "url/to/api";

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  get(id: number) {
    return this._http.get(this.baseHost + id + '/show.json')
      .map(data => data.json()).toPromise();
  }
}
```

(Component: car-detail.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarService } from "app/car/car.service";
import { Car, User } from "app/car/car";


import { JsonConvert } from "json2typescript"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-detail',
  templateUrl: './car-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-detail.component.css'] 
})
export class CarDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public car:Car = new Car();
  public createdBy:User = new User();
  constructor(private _carService: CarService) { }

  getCar(){
    return this._carService
               .get(1) 
               .then(
                  data =>
                   {this.car = JsonConvert.deserializeString(JSON.stringify(data), Car);
                    this.createdBy = JsonConvert.deserializeString(JSON.stringify(data.createdby), User); 
                    console.log(data,JSON.stringify(data))
                  });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCar();
  }

}
```

(car-detail.html)

```
<p>
  car-detail works!
</p>
<p>
  {{car.brand}} print: FORD 
</p>
<p>
  {{car.createdBy.email}} print: email@email.com //It's ok but this line is the problem  
</p>
<p>
  {{createdBy.email}} print: email@email.com
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component creates a new `Car` and assigns it to its `car` field. The `createdBy` field of this car object is set to undefined. And the template tries to display the property `email` of the car's `createdBy`, which is undefined. Hence the error.

Use

```
{{car.createdBy?.email}}
```

or

```
<p *ngIf="car.createdBy">
  {{ car.createdBy.email }}
</p>
```

to avoid the error.